How to ingest ERA5-Land orography to Google Earth Engine?
I would like to have elevation data associated with ERA5-Land dataset in Google Earth Engine. As far as I'm aware these data are not currently available in GEE, so I need to upload as a user asset.
I have downloaded the geopotential file supplied as netcdf by ECMWF, which has a size of 3600 x 1801 pixels, whereas the ERA5-Land image collections in Earth Engine are 3601 x 1801. In the netcdf, the longitude variable (length==3600) has values 0 to 359.9 spaced every 0.1 degrees.
How do I need to modify the geopotential data to conform to the GEE image collections so that elevations correctly align with the climate data? (I am working in the javascript code editor)

You mean you want to remap the dataset?

possibly...will that give me a 3601x1801 grid?
